# What kind of binary search tree is it used to implement `std::set`?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

In cplusplus.com, in [the reference page of `std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), you can read the following:

> Sets are typically implemented as binary search trees.

Does anyone know what kind of binary search tree is it used? I suppose it is used a balanced binary tree, but which one?

Comment: That is entirely up to the implementor of the standard library implementation. As there are quite a number of different implementations out there, this question could be difficult to answer completely.

Comment: It doesn't even **have to** be a binary search tree ("typically") (but I believe most, if not all, implementations are).

Comment: It's implementation specific, put red-black trees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) are quite common.

Comment: I knew it depends on the implementation, but I thought that a specific data structure is typically used.

Comment: @arne What you say is true in practice, but all of the implementations I know ultimately derive from Stepanov's sources, and use the same basic data structures and algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Red-Black Tree.

Type `#include <set>` on visual studio and right-click to see the implementation.

Can also be found here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01520_source.html

Comment: While most implementations do use a red-black try, it's certainly not required.